# Unable to install serverless framework on macosx

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework

Actually I'm unable to install serverless on my Mac.

Here are some information about my config:

- OSX Yosemite 10.10.5
- node.js 6.2.10
- npm 3.10.10

Command launched to install serveless :

```
sudo npm -g install serverless
```

result :

```
/usr/local/bin/serverless -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless
/usr/local/bin/slss -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless
/usr/local/bin/sls -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless

serverless@1.11.0 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless
node ./scripts/postinstall.js
Unhandled rejection SyntaxError: Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 1
at Object.parse (native)
at exports.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/rc/lib/utils.js:15:17)
at addConfigFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/rc/index.js:31:20)
at Array.forEach (native)
at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/rc/index.js:44:36)
at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/get-proxy/index.js:2:25)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/caw/index.js:3:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Could be that your `~/.npmrc` file is invalid. The error is thrown by the `rc` module, which is used by `get-proxy` to retrieve the current NPM proxy setting from a bunch of sources mentioned [here](https://github.com/dominictarr/rc#standards) (where `${appname}` should `npm`).

Comment: Tried to remove `~/.npmrc` file and it works, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace suggests that the [`rc`](https://github.com/dominictarr/rc) module is causing the error.

That module is used by a module called [`get-proxy`](https://github.com/kevva/get-proxy) to determine if there are any HTTP/HTTPS proxies configured. It's trying to [read the NPM configuration](https://github.com/kevva/get-proxy/blob/a7226ad85c6ecf20f4f55cd273f3d9481fc6aa6d/index.js#L2), which is typically stored in a file called `~/.npmrc`

The error suggests there's an issue with that file.